# What are auxiliary classes?

Tags: java, class

What are Auxiliary classes in Java, how does some one write one, and how does the compiler know that something is an Auxiliary class?

The reason I ask this is because the compiler is generating a warning regarding an object in an external library:

```
warning: auxiliary class Pattern in jregex/Pattern.java should not be accessed from outside its own source file
```

and I want to know why

Comment: There is sure some good humour here possible, Aux being a second class, steerage class.  However, think of it more as a pattern you way wish to look and search for "object Patterns"

Comment: You need to provide more information. In your case "Auxilary" may be the name of actual class in that library.

Comment: It is just a warning, so you shouldn't be concerned. However, are you sure that class name matches file name?

Comment: I know, but I am writing this program for scratch and I want all warnings solved or suppressed (if I know what I am doing), so they won't make it hard to find errors in the output.

Comment: @Artem Warnings should almost always be concerning. At least in my experience. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As descried in Java specification [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.3), you can specify more than one class in one .java file. The class which name matches .java file name will be the main class which can be declared public and be visible to other classes. All other classes in the file therefore are "auxilary" classes. Auxilary class can NOT be declared public and (as @trashgod rightfully pointed out) therefore they only be declared with package-private access. For instance for AClass.java file:

```
public class AClass {
    private AuxilaryClass a;
}
class AuxilaryClass {
    private int b;
}
```

AuxilaryClass class can't be public and is not visible outside this AClass.java file.

However, using auxilary classes considered extremely bad style and against [Java Code Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141855.html#11684). Please use separate or [inner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) classes if really needed.

Edit: The term "Auxilary" is not Oracle/Sun official terminology. It has been introduced (or used) here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=miTM9rY3He0 and/or here: http://doc.sumy.ua/prog/java/langref/ch05_03.htm

Comment: Your link doesn't contain the word "auxiliary" anywhere in it. Did you link to the wrong place? If this is what you intended to link to, how do you know that this is what's meant by auxiliary in the OP's question?

Comment: Yeah, because Java specification does not call them that way. They are named "Auxilary" here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=miTM9rY3He0

Comment: `AuxilaryClass` has [*package-private*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) access.

Comment: No @trashgod, your link is only related to main classes. Just try to test it - you'll see.

Comment: @trashgod I just tried. In addition to the AClass.java file I've provided create B.java file in the same package: package test;

import test.AuxilaryClass;

public class C {
 AuxilaryClass e;
 
}
It won't compile in Java 8.

Comment: Yes, `AuxilaryClass` and its public members should be visible in `B`.

Comment: They are not. Please try.

Comment: @trashgod is of course correct - those members are package-private. I just tried it myself, in case I was misremembering: another class in the same package has access to this "auxiliary class" and its public members.

Comment: @amalloy: Thank you for elaborating; I should add that `B` also has access to the _package-private_ member `b` in an instance of `AuxilaryClass`.

Comment: Hey guys, I apologize, you are correct, it looks like I had some kind of temporarily issue with my Eclipse Java 8 beta support. It compiled fine after restart. I will update the answer.

Comment: NB: The [preview of sealed classes](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/360) introduced in Java 15 uses auxiliary classes as known subclasses of a main sealed class (`Shape`).

Answer (score 1):

An auxiliary class isn't any kind of official or technical thing as far as I know. Someone might describe a class as auxiliary if it were addressing a secondary concern, or something, but the compiler doesn't have any idea what an auxiliary class is, and neither do I.

In general, if you have error messages from the computer, please *paste them in their entirety*. If you think the compiler is upset about an auxiliary class, paste the error message: someone else will be able to make sense of it, whereas currently it's being filtered through some kind of confusion that's made you think auxiliary classes are a real thing!