# Is really “No Public Class” reachable within its package?

Tags: java

In "Think in Java", the author says:

> You just leave the **"public"** keyword off the class, in which case it has **package access**. (That class can be used only within that package.)

To prove this, I create one public class and one no-public class:

```
package com.ciaoshen.thinkinjava.chapter7;
import java.util.*;

//My public class
public class PublicClass {
    //default constructor
    public PublicClass(){
        System.out.println("Hello, I am PublicClass.");
    }
}

//Non public class
//It should be package reachable
class PackageReachableClass {
    //default constructor
    PackageReachableClass(){
        System.out.println("Hi, I am PackageReachableClass.");
    }
}
```

But when I call them from another class in the same package:

```
public class InPackageClass {

/**
 *  MAIN
 *  @param args void
 */
public static void main(String[] args){
    //pubic class can be reached from anywhere
    PublicClass newPublicClass=new PublicClass();
    //non-public-class should be accessable in the same package
    PackageReachableClass newPackageReachableClass =new PackageReachableClass();
}
}
```

The system warning me: **The no-public class should not be accessed from outside its own source file.**

```
/Users/Wei/java/com/ciaoshen/thinkinjava/chapter7/InPackageClass.java:22: warning: auxiliary class PackageReachableClass in ./com/ciaoshen/thinkinjava/chapter7/PublicClass.java should not be accessed from outside its own source file
        PackageReachableClass newPackageReachableClass =new PackageReachableClass();
        ^
/Users/Wei/java/com/ciaoshen/thinkinjava/chapter7/InPackageClass.java:22: warning: auxiliary class PackageReachableClass in ./com/ciaoshen/thinkinjava/chapter7/PublicClass.java should not be accessed from outside its own source file
        PackageReachableClass newPackageReachableClass =new PackageReachableClass();
                                                            ^
2 warnings
Hello, I am PublicClass.
Hi, I am PackageReachableClass.
```

So here comes my question: Is the no-public class still package reachable? And why Java forbid us to call them from another file in the same package if this is totally legal?

Comment: Is `PackageReachableClass` in it's own file, e.g. `PackageReachableClass.java`?

Comment: It's a warning. That means you _can_ do it, but it might indicate you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @cricket_007 No, `PackageReachabelClass` and `PublicClass` are in the same file called `PublicClass.java`.  And I am trying to call them from another file `InPackageClass.java` .

Comment: Just put this `PackageReachableClass` into PackageReachableClass.java file

Comment: **Is the no-public class still package reachable?** Just try it? **And why Java forbid us to call them from another file in the same package** It doesn't?

Comment: In one file there can only be one public class which is the same as the name of the file. The reason you see the warning is because you have the package private class in the same file as the public class. Do what @Antoniossss suggested, and you'd see the expected behaviour.

Comment: @khelwood  Is that means put several no public class in a single file is not an appropriate  style?

Comment: @Antoniossss yeah, when I put it into a new file, the warning is gone.

Comment: @RahulSharma So put everything in a single file is not a good practice? And we should always create a new `.java` file for each single class right?

Comment: By convention every public, nonstatic class of name "X" must be placed into separate X.java file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only a warning that you have defined an [auxiliary class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521288/what-are-auxiliary-classes).

> auxiliary class PackageReachableClass in PublicClass.java

Which means you have one Java file with 2 classes, which is against [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141855.html#11684). (Emphasis mine).

> Each Java source file contains a single public class or interface. When **private** classes and interfaces are associated with a public class, you can put them in the same source file as the public class. The public class should be the first class or interface in the file.

To correctly test your package-private classes, please separate the two classes into separate files based on their class name, i.e. `PublicClass.java` and `PackageReachableClass.java`.

Comment: Don't duplicate answers. Add to the existing answer in the duplicate instead if you have something new to add.

Comment: This question was about package-private. That answer was about auxiliary classes. This answer is how to interpret the warning and mitigate it. Therefore, I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: The question is misguided because of incorrect (or misleading) example code to start with. Once that example code is "fixed", there is no confusion left. Hence, the question is answered by resolving the confusion. And all of that is still no reason to duplicate the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys. I just did't find the same question with such a title "What are auxiliary class" :p

Comment: @weiShen really? Because googling "auxiliary class" gives that as exact first result. Google your errors/warnings for future reference.

Comment: @weiShen The exact phrase I searched was from your "warning: auxiliary class in"

Comment: @JeroenVannevel haha, but at that moment, I did't know that calls "auxiliary class" XD

Comment: @weiShen it's literally in the warning message.

Comment: @cricket_007  so I searched for something like "package-private class" or "no-public class".  Actually I am reading "Thinking in Java", and the author did't mention that "auxiliary class" is a bad coding style. Any way, thx for yr answer:)

Comment: @weiShen it is not "bad practice" to have aux classes, only to write your code that way, that they are accessed but the code from outside of main class context