# What is auxiliary methods in Java?

Tags: java, methods, data-structures

I was searching for an answer in Google but I could not find a single one.
I hope someone here could help me, I need to know what are auxiliary methods in Java.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe this helps (even it is about classes): [What are auxiliary classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521288/what-are-auxiliary-classes)

Comment: They're a name somebody invented that doesn't actually mean anything.  No, seriously, "auxiliary methods" is not actually a well-defined term.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you might need to define a function inside another function to handle your problem. Here, you need a function that called auxiliary method. Generally, when you want to solve your problem in recursive approach, you need auxiliary method.